# How to make dropdown menu height of screen so that it overrides page height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown menu which I'd like to make only as big or as small as the screen size, meaning it would cover screen height regardless of page height and not show the page beneath or below it. At the moment it covers the screen on some pages but it scrolls and is a bit too big as, in order to hide the whole page when toggled, I've had to increase height.

```
<div class="module widget- 
handle mobile-toggle right 
visible-sm visible-xs"><a 
id="mobile-nav" href="#">
<div class="container1" 
onclick="myFunction(this)">
<div class="bar1"></div>
<div class="bar2"></div>
<div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
</a> 
<script>
function myFunction(x){
x.classList.toggle
('change');
}</script>               
</div>
<div class="module-group right">
                        <div class="module left">
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"><ul id="menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-15050" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-15050 dropdown"><a title="Contact" href="https://4309.co.uk/contact/">Contact
```

Css to increase height of container on drop.

```
@media(max-width: 768px). 
{.collapse {position: 
absolute; height: 775px; 
background-color:white; z- 
index: 99999 !important; 
top:75px; left: -50px; 
line-height: 10px;}}
```

So how do set it to always be the same size as the screen and to cover the screen, regardless of height? Some pages it covers the whole screen but is too high (increased to cover page height) , others the page shows below it and increasing size to the larger page heights would make it massive.

[mobile](https://4309.co.uk)

Someone helpfully suggested using

```
var x = "Total Height: " + screen.height;
```

But how would i incorporate this into my existing function above and here

```
function myFunction(x){
x.classList.toggle
('change');
```

Could I do

```
function myFunction(x){
x.classList.toggle; var x = "Total Height: " + screen.height;
('change');
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Use `screen.width;` and `screen.height;` to get the exact size for your dropdown. 
see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp

Comment: Thanks. So how would i incorporate in my javascript: `function myFunction(x){
x.classList.toggle
('change');`

Comment: You can give it as absolute height in your css.